# Is there a way to determine if CSS class is active in HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

this is more a curiosity of mine, I don't know if it's something possible.
If I am inside a HTML page, is there a way to quickly determine if a CSS class is active inside that page? 
I explain better, let's say I am inside a website with a list of different users and near their avatar I may have a green badge for online users, while others has grey badge.
If this list is really long, is there a way to programmatically (or at least quicker than scrolling and looking by myself) detect which users are online?
I thought they have a different active CSS class but I don't know how to look for it.
Thanks

NOTE: I know how to detect an element, but if there's a list of elements I need to know which of them has a particular class active

Comment: do mean the active or green users will have a ".active" class??

Answer (score 0):

you can use (inspect) in chrome `ctrl`+`shift`+`i` in inspect element you can see which css is active or not right side
[image: you can see active or inactive css right side]

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Placing the code below within your developer console should display the length of the existing classNames if they exist.

```
const classes = document.querySelectorAll(".className");

console.log(className.length);
```

You should then be able to navigate the `classes` for the relevant information by navigating the object trees returned for each object found by the `querySelectorAll` method.

But there may be times where this may not be the true count to the data set. 
For example, if the data is dynamically loaded during page scrolling. You can then add an iterator loop to detect when you have reached the bottom of the page and push to the classes array.